# Unable to create helm template for field in values.yaml file containing {}

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Here's my ***values.yaml*** file containing array of canary steps

```
istio:
  canary:
    enabled: true
    steps:
    - setWeight: 10
    - pause: {}
    - setWeight: 20
    - pause: { duration: 20 }
    - setWeight: 30
    - pause: {}
    - setWeight: 40
    - pause: { duration: 20 }
    - setWeight: 50
    - pause: {}
    - setWeight: 75
    - pause: { duration: 20 }
    - setWeight: 90
    - pause: {}
```

I want to get the array of ***steps*** from values.yaml to following ***argos-rollout.yaml:***

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Rollout
metadata:
  name: my-rollout
spec:
  strategy:
    canary:
      steps:
        <?>
```

I tried many combinations but nothing is working like the following gives me
***error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context***

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Rollout
metadata:
  name: my-rollout
spec:
  strategy:
    canary:
      steps:
      {{- range .Values.istio.canary.steps }}
        - {{ toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

Can I please get some suggestions to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Just write out the whole list as-is.  If you're not transforming the values at all you don't need a `range` loop, just pass the entire list to `toYaml`.

```yaml
spec:
  strategy:
    canary:
      steps:
{{ toYaml .Values.istio.canary.steps | indent 8 }}
```

Note in the last line that I've put the `toYaml` call on its own line, and since it's going to be `indent`ed, there is no white space at the start of the line.

If you do need to iterate through the items, you need to `indent` them as you've shown, but then having done that you need to `trim` out the leading whitespace from the first line.

```yaml
      steps:
{{- range .Values.istio.canary.steps }}
        - {{ toYaml . | indent 8 | trim }}
{{- end }}
```

You can use `helm template --debug` to see what's coming out of this template, even if it's not entirely valid YAML.